# How can I create an accordion using OOJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a function that allows you to click on an item in a group of items, and collapse and expand the height of the specific item that was clicked. However, currently, whatever item is clicked, expands and collapses all of them. I'm not sure what the best approach is.

```
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="myDiv" data-state="open" id="1"></div>
<div class="myDiv" data-state="open" id="2"></div>
<div class="myDiv" data-state="open" id="3"></div>
<div class="myDiv" data-state="open" id="4"></div>

</div>
```

`

```
class Height {
  constructor(el) {
    this.element = el;
  }

  get state(){
    return $(this.element).attr('data-state');
  }

  set _state(newState){
    $(this.element).attr('data-state',newState);
  }

  expand() {
    $(this.element).css('height', '200px');
    this._state = 'open';
  }

  collapse() {
    $(this.element).css('height', '50px');
    this._state = 'close';
  }

  toggle(){
     if(this.state == 'open') {
        this.collapse();
    } else if(this.state == 'close') {
        this.expand();
    }
  }
}
var myDiv = $('.myDiv');

var myDivInstance = new Height(myDiv);

$('body').on('click', function() {
  myDivInstance.toggle();
});
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/Woodenchops/pen/ZwrBwB?editors=1011

Comment: Right now they are all reacting the same because they are being toggled by the common class `.myDiv` rather than individually by id

Comment: No need to use id specific code  but you do need to loop over the whole collection to create instances of your js class for each element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st answer (not OOP):

i've rewrote your code in a simplier manner, i hope it does fit your needs.

```
$('.myDiv').on('click', function()
{
 switch ($(this).css("height")) 
 {
  case "200px":
   $(this).css("height","50px");
   break;
  case "50px":
   $(this).css("height","200px");
   break;
  default:
   $(this).css("height","50px");
   break;
 }
});
```

what mainly went wrong on your click event is, that u wrote a listener for the whole body-tag instead of each element.

the selector ('.myDiv') could easily be replaced with ('.wrapper *'), so each child of the wrapper-class would get those click-behaviours and those hardcoded numbers for the pixels could be replaced with variables, but thats up to you. I hope this helps, because i'm still new to JS and Jquery.

2nd answer(OOP):

```
$('.myDiv').on('click', function() {
var myDivInstance = new Height(this);
myDivInstance.toggle();
});
```

after declaring your class this is what the click-eventhandler could look like.
this builds an object each time a div is clicked and toggles it.
I hope this answer fits to your needs.

Comment: Hey, appreciate the feedback, man. It is simpler. But defeats the purpose of the OOJS approach.

Comment: I definitely agree with you WoodenChops that the point of using object oriented programming is to make code more complicated!

Comment: Nice one! ha. We have a Keyboard Warrior, ladies and gentlemen. Mate, I'm just trying to use a simple example. Yes, its overkill for this example, but, I'm trying to practise for larger scale projects.

Comment: I've edited my answer to fit your declared class and react in a more oop-style